# How Web server handle TCP connection?

Tags: web, tcp, webserver

I am tring to write a small Web server. And I am trying to understand how Web server should handle the TCP connection.

My understanding is, client requests arrive at the web server on its 80 port. Web server has a dedicated monitoring thread (or many?) listening on port 80. And the monitoring thread put an work item for each of the incoming requests into a queue for later process. The work item data should include the client IP address and client port info.

Then worker threads will take requests from the queue and send back responses to clients. The TCP connection tuple will look like this < server IP, port 80, client IP, client port >

So, my question is,

- Can there be more than one monitoring threads? And are there multiple queues or a single queue with synchronized access among multiple monitoring and worker threads?
- Can the work items on the queue have inter-relationship? If not, does this mean the loss of state of subsequent requests?
- Is it possible that the single port 80 be used by many worker threads to create outbound connection? I mean, port 80 is used by many server worker threads at the same time to create TCP connection like below. And these connections are used for sending responses to different clients.

  < server IP, port ***80***, client IP 1, client port 1 >

  < server IP, port ***80***, client IP 2, client port 2 >

  < server IP, port ***80***, client IP 3, client port 3 >

  ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can there be more than one monitoring threads?

Yes.

> And are there multiple queues or a single queue with synchronized access among multiple monitoring and worker threads?

Whichever suits you.

> Can the work items on the queue have inter-relationship?

Only if the original requests do, which is up to how the clients are written.

> If not, does this mean the loss of state of subsequent requests?

does *what* mean the loss of state?

> Is it possible that the single port 80 be used by many worker threads to create outbound connection?

No, but workers don't create outbound connections. They reply over the same connection the request was received on.

Comment: Thanks. Let me refine my question. *Is it possible that the single port 80 be used in multiple TCP connections at the same time?* I think it should be possible because port number is nothing but a logical identification of server side application. And from the server's perspective, the packets to different client addresses are sent out in an interleaved way over the wire.

Comment: @smwikipedia Yes. Have a look at a `netstat` output on a busy HTTP server. You will see a `LISTENING` port 80 and dozens of `ESTABLISHED` port 80s, which are the accepted connections. Interleaving has nothing to do with it.

Comment: By interleaving, what I want to say is, packets targeted to different clients have to share the same wire. As you mentioned, workers don't create outbound connections. But there must be thread sending out the responses. And maybe more than one. These responses must be sent *concurrently* rather than *sequentially*, so they have to be interleaved. I just want to get a precise picture about the server working paradigm.

Comment: Don't worry about the  wire. It's a packet switching protocol.